# Displaying ~ for $HOME in zsh prompt

Tags: zsh, prompt

I have my prompt set to the following:

```
PROMPT=%F{reset}[%F{blue}%2/%F{reset}]
```

which displays two parent directories as

```
[foo/bar]
```

However, when I'm in `$HOME` or one directory deep in `$HOME`, I'd like the prompt to be displayed as

```
[~]
[~/foo]
```

respectively, instead of

```
[/Users/me]
[me/foo]
```

I've tried approaches like Steve Losh's [`collapse_pwd`](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/02/my-extravagant-zsh-prompt/) (and the simpler version: `${PWD/#$HOME/~}` also mentioned in the article) and other similar ones, but I lose the flexibility of being able to show only the last two directories.

How can I modify the above to handle `$HOME`? My zsh version is `zsh 5.0.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0.0)` on OS X 10.8.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`zsh` has built-in support for that. Use `%2~` instead of `%2/`. See also `%40<...<%~`

See also the `autonamedirs` option:

```
$ l=/usr/local
$ PS1='%~$ '
~$ setopt autonamedirs
~$ cd /usr/local
~l$
```

(without `autonamedirs`, you can still do `cd ~l` to `cd` to `/usr/local` and your prompt to show `~l`).